# Income cohorts based on household size

Tags: data-request, us-census, income

I am looking for income cohort data by household size for USA, preferably 2014. This is not available in Census FactFinder and I am not sure where else to look. Could anyone guide me on this, please.

Comment: So you are not looking for median income by house hold size? (http://censusreporter.org/data/table/?table=B19019&geo_ids=01000US,040|01000US&primary_geo_id=01000US)

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you are defining income "cohort" data? It seems, at first glance, like you are requesting a cross-tabulation of income ranges by household size. But we would need clarification.

Comment: It is indeed that @Kotebiya

Comment: @Skram I would specifically need cohort wise data rather than the median since I want to know how many households of a given size are in the income cohort, say $10000-$15000. This, I cannot get from the median information. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 4):

you can compute this with the cps or scf microdata

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/current%20population%20survey%20%28cps%29

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/survey%20of%20consumer%20finances%20%28scf%29